# SGE hold_jid and catching failed jobs

Tags: sungridengine

I have a script that submits a number of jobs to run in parallel on an SGE queue, and another gathering script that is executed when this list of jobs are finished. I am using `-hold_jid wc_job_list` to hold the execution of the gathering script while the parallel jobs are running.

I just noticed that sometimes some of the parallel jobs fail and the gathering script still runs. The documentation states that:

> If any of the referenced jobs exits with exit code 100, the submitted
>   job will remain ineligible for execution.

How can I catch the parallel failed jobs exit status so that if any of them fail for any reason, the gathering script is not executed or gives an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of `BASH`, you could parse the exit status of your program (can be referenced as `$?`) and in the case of not being `0` (which is the exit status for normal termination), call `exit 100` at the end of your jobscript.

The problem with this is, that your job will remain in the queue in state `Eqw` and has to be deleted manually.

**UPDATE:** For every job you set to `Eqw` your administrators get an email...